# Process inside a process

Tags: c#, python, process

I have a C# code that runs some python code (as a process).
The python code itself opens a different process. 
The process the python code opens will definitely finish after the process the C# code opens would finish.
My question is the following:

If I'd do:

```
Process p = new Process();
//some code
p.Start();
p.waitForExit();
//Some more code
```

Would the some more code execute when the python process finishes or when the process that the python opens?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how the python code opens the process. If the python code is waiting (like you are in your c# code above) for the child process to finish, then the "some more code" will execute after both the child processes are done.
If the python process starts the child process and terminates (while the child process is still running), then the "some more code" will execute after the python process terminates, but not necessarily the before the child-of-python-process terminates.